# Is there any faster way to add the component in list? Maybe a loop?

Tags: python

I want to add the last component in individual list. Doing it manually from addition operator is easy for small data set. Is there any alternative method which i can use to  add those components for over 1000 of lists?

```
   data=[
[514.8,526.9,512,525,27942414],
[527.9, 528.5,  507.15, 510.8,  19353195],
[510    ,522.2  ,504.8  ,520.85 ,21799071],
[519.95,    523.2,  512,    515.7   ,18364451],
[510.4  ,513.85 ,494.25 ,501.85 ,17946821],
]
sum_volume=(data[0][4]+data[1][4]+data[2][4]+data[3][4]+data[4][4])
print(sum_volume)
```

Comment: `sum(row[-1] for row in data)` should work, although you might want to look into `numpy` or `pandas`.

Comment: If you have a large data set, you already shouldn't use plain Python lists. Use NumPy or Pandas to store data. They're much faster because implemented in C++, and they also provide many convenient functions, e.g. for your sum it could be `data[:, 4].sum()`

Comment: Use a for (or for each) loop to add the fourth value in each array in data to your sum variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can "transpose" your list, so the last column (4) would be the last list:

```
sum(list(zip(*data))[-1])
```

The part `zip(*data)` zips each list with each other. What zip does is:

```
list(zip([1, 2], [3, 4]))
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Or for your data:

```
list(zip(*data))

[(514.8, 527.9, 510, 519.95, 510.4),
 (526.9, 528.5, 522.2, 523.2, 513.85),
 (512, 507.15, 504.8, 512, 494.25),
 (525, 510.8, 520.85, 515.7, 501.85),
 (27942414, 19353195, 21799071, 18364451, 17946821)]
```

I use `list(zip())` because `zip` will return an iterable object (`<zip>`). You can also choose to put it in a `tuple`, or in a `for loop`.

So when you unpack your data, your new rows (list indices) are the old columns.

In this case I selected the last column,`[-1]` but that is equal to `[4]` in your case.

```
fourth_column = list(zip(*data))[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension and slice. `-1` means first from last.

```py
sum_volume = sum([d[-1] for d in data])
```

This equivalent to:

```py
last_components = []
for d in data:
  last_components.append(d[-1])

sum_volume = sum(last_components)
```

Answer (score 0):

`This is a basic way to do that, Also easy to understand.`

```py
sum_volume=0
data=[
[514.8,526.9,512,525,27942414],
[527.9, 528.5,  507.15, 510.8,  19353195],
[510    ,522.2  ,504.8  ,520.85 ,21799071],
[519.95,    523.2,  512,    515.7   ,18364451],
[510.4  ,513.85 ,494.25 ,501.85 ,17946821],
]
for i in range(len(data)):
    sum_volume+=data[i][4]
print(sum_volume)
```

**There is another way**

```py
data=[
[514.8,526.9,512,525,27942414],
[527.9, 528.5,  507.15, 510.8,  19353195],
[510    ,522.2  ,504.8  ,520.85 ,21799071],
[519.95,    523.2,  512,    515.7   ,18364451],
[510.4  ,513.85 ,494.25 ,501.85 ,17946821],
]

sum_volume = sum([i[4] for i in data])
```

Comment: `sum_volume = [sum(i[4]) for i in data]` should be `sum_volume = sum([i[4] for i in data])` (replace the position of the sum function).